# gsutil cp -r requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, billing

I'm developing a job that could potentially create millions of files (images). I'll use a total of 500mi files just as an example.

If I use `gsutil cp -r` to copy the folder that includes all these files organized into subfolders, is each file upload charged as a class A operation OR is it only charged once, as an operation?

Answer (score 2):

The CLI command will run a copy for each object in the folder, so the operation charge is for each object in the folder.

The [operations pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) notes that a single CLI command may result in multiple operation calls:

> Tools such as the Google Cloud console, gsutil, and the Cloud Storage client libraries might use two or more operations to perform a task. For example, when you click on a bucket name in the Google Cloud console, the system performs an operation to get the list of objects in the bucket and a separate operation to get the metadata for the bucket.

The [storage transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/pricing) (similar to `gsutil cp`) also has the list of operations performed on your behalf during a data transfer.